# GNU make: inverting sub-process success?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've a make file for a scripted system, with a lot of tests which should pass. Each test is a separate call to the scripting application:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# run test scripts in the module::test
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
scripted_tests: bin/kin modules/test/actor_equality.kin modules/test/actor_fibre.kin ...
    bin/kin modules/test/actor_equality.kin
    bin/kin modules/test/actor_fibre.kin
    ...
```

Which is fine. I also have some similar tests which should return failure. I know that `-` will ignore the return status, but there must be something simple to invert the return status so I can run

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# run test scripts in the module::test::errors
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
inverse_tests: bin/kin modules/test/error/bad_function.kin ...
    not bin/kin modules/test/error/bad_function.kin
    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `!` command.

```
echo This returns success
! echo This returns failure
```

Comment: Specifically, its "! bin/kin" rather than "!bin/kin", which I tried and got an error

Comment: Very useful when using grep to test for the presence of an error message in build log output.
`! grep output.log -i "error msg"`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to make sure that the exit status of "bin/kin test5.kin" is 5. Then just write this:

```
run-test5:
  bin/kin test5.bin; test $$? = 5
```

For more elaborated tests see 'help test' and 'man test'.

Note: I tend to avoid exclamation marks because it is typically impossible to copy/paste them into an interactive shell (since it searches the history).